# "Would you have liked to have been" vs. "would you have liked to be"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, past-tense, infinitives

I was interested in the following sentence which appeared in an article titled “[No Rest for the Weary](http://learning.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/02/15/no-rest-for-the-weary/)” in The New York Times (February 15, 2008).

> Would you have liked **to have been** president from 1862-1864?

It sounds ungrammatical to my ear as the journalists (MICHELLE SALE and YASMIN CHIN EISENHAUER) did use "to have been" rather than "to be", but I am not able to find what rules govern this problem.

So, I would write:

> Would you have liked **to be** president from 1862-1864?

Am I right? If so, why?

Comment: The quote is grammatical.  The date range is in the past, and so must be the verb phrase.  If a similar question was being asked about the present tense, it would read *would you like to be president from 2012-2016?* so that *like* and *to be* agree the way that *have liked* and *to have been* agree.

Comment: There's a detailed discussion of this question on Language Log: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3941 .

Answer (score 8):

It's grammatical, but it's probably not what the journalist intended.  *Would you like to have been president...* asks whether election in the past would please you as you are now; *would you have liked to be...*  asks whether a 'you' in the 19th century would have wanted to be president; *would you have liked to have been...* is asking whether an election in 1862 would have pleased you as you were sometime between 1863 and last year.

Answer (score 1):

I think your observation is sound.

I know these of Conditionals:

(If you were given the chance), would you like to be President? - Present Conditional

(If you had been born in that century), would you have liked to be President? - Past Conditional