# Difference between some sentences involving tense

Tags: differences, tenses, subjunctive-mood

What is the difference between the two sentences in each of the three cases?

> 1A. I should like to have sat down.
>
> 1B. I should have liked to sit down.
>
> 2A. He acts as if he knows the subject.
>
> 2B. He acts as if he knew the subject.
>
> 3A. He felt better when she gave him medicine.
>
> 3B. He was feeling better when she gave him medicine.

The first pair confounds me the most.

Comment: What do you think or doubt is the difference? Why does the first one confounds you?

Comment: This is really three unrelated questions in one. Stack Exchange works best when you limit your question to one question.

Comment: @Mohit: Only helpful answers please.

Comment: @RegDwighт, this is the first time that I am using this site so thank you for advice. Nonetheless, could someone answer these?

Comment: To ping people, prefix their names with an at. Otherwise they won't get your message. I have fixed your comments accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first pair, you might like to take a look at [this question and the answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100780/i-would-have-liked-to-have-seen-to-see-new-york-before-the-cyclone/100852#100852). Based on the methodology I used in my own answer there, in A *I should like* refers to the time of speaking and *to have sat down* refers to some previous time. In B, on the other hand, *I should have liked* refers to the same time as the sitting down.

In the second pair, A suggests that the speaker does know the subject, while B suggests that the speaker might not.

In the third pair, A suggests that the medicine made him feel better, while B suggests that he was feeling better before she gave him the medicine.

All of these explanations should be read with a certain amount of caution. Much will depend on the circumstances in which they are being said or written.

Comment: Oh, come on, down-voter, whoever you are, let's hear what you have to say. We might all benefit.